# Cooling something by applying a decreasing temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, thermal-conductivity, convection, cooling

I've recently come across **Fourier's Heat Equation**: $k \cdot \nabla^2 \; T = \rho c \cdot \dot{T}$ and the solution to **Newton's Law of Cooling**: $T(t)=\left(T_\text{initial} - T_\text{cool}\right) \cdot \mathrm e^{-\alpha t} + T_\text{cool}$ for a constant cooling temperature. Does this equation still hold when $T_\text{cool}$ itself is a function of time?

In other words, does $T(t)=\left[T_\text{initial} - T_\text{cool}(t)\right] \cdot\mathrm e^{-\alpha t} + T_\text{cool}(t)$ accurately represent a cooling process when the cooling temperature is for example $T_\text{cool}(t)=T_\text{start} - \frac{t}{5}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly:

$$k \cdot \nabla^2 \; T = \rho c \cdot \dot{T}\tag{1}$$

is NOT the "lumped capacity heat conduction equation" and:

$$T(t)=\left(T_{initial} - T_{cool}\right) \cdot e^{-\alpha t} + T_{cool}\tag{2}$$

is NOT "its one-dimensional solution".

Rather, $(1)$ is the [Fourier Heat Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Statement_of_the_equation) and $(2)$ is the solution of [Newton's Law of Cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_cooling#Heat_transfer_version_of_the_law), for $T_{cool}=\text{constant}$.

Lumped thermal analysis in fact uses Newton's Law of Cooling by assuming the **temperature of the cooling body is uniform in space** (that is what 'lumped' really means here). Fourier's equation does not require this.

> Does this equation still hold when $T_{cool}$ itself is a function of
>   time?

**NO**. But Newton's Cooling Law can be written, taken that in mind, as:

$$\frac{\text{d}Q}{\text{d}t}=-hA[T(t)-T_{cool}(t)]\tag{3}$$

where $T_{cool}(t)$ is a function of time.

With:
$$\text{d}Q=mc_p\text{d}T(t)$$

we have:

$$\frac{\text{d}T(t)}{\text{d}t}=-k[T(t)-T_{cool}(t)]\tag{4}$$
where $k=\frac{hA}{mc_p}$ (not to be confused with the same symbol in $(1)$)

$(4)$ is a 1st order ordinary differential equation. **Whether it has an analytical solution will depend strongly on the shape of $T_{cool}(t)$.** $(4)$ can be rewritten as:

$$T'+kT=f(t)$$

Again, depending on $f(t)$, this can often be tackled using [an integrating factor](http://www.mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/mathcentre-ode.pdf).

The OP suggested that:

$$f(t)=k(a-bt)$$

So we have:

$$T'+kT=k(a-bt)$$

The integrating factor is:

$$I=e^{\int k \text{d}t}=e^{kt}$$

$$IT'+kIT=k(a-bt)I$$

$$\int(IT'+kIT)\text{d}t=\int k(a-bt)I\text{d}t$$

$$e^{kt}T=\int k(a-bt)I\text{d}t=\int k(a-bt)e^{kt}\text{d}t$$

$$e^{kt}T=ka\int e^{kt}\text{d}t-kb\int t e^{kt}\text{d}t$$

$$e^{kt}T=a e^{kt}-e^{kt}\frac{b(kt-1)}{k}+C$$

So that:

$$T(t)=a-\frac{b(kt-1)}{k}+Ce^{-kt}\tag{5}$$

Apply the initial condition to determine $C$.

You can see how it's fundamentally different from $(2)$ because it contains a linear term.

That Eq. $(5)$ is in all likelihood correct can be seen for $t \gg 0$ because then the exponential term vanishes and we get:

$$T(t)=a-bt=T_{cool}(t)$$

So $T(t)$ tends asymptotically to $T_{cool}$.

Comment: I have corrected my original post to use the right names for those formulas. I will give this solution a try, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: I didn't really see your last line so I'll now include an answer to that.

Comment: I leave the numerical side to you.

Comment: So just to make sure we're on the same page, your f(t) = a - b.t is actually k.T_c(t) right? In other words, if T_c(t) = p - q.t, then a = p.k and b = q.k? (hate that there is no mathjax for comments)

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But Mathjax works in the comments too, e.g.:  $T_c(t) = p - q.t$

Comment: I just re-read Newton's original derivation of cooling and he related the rate of change of the *temperature difference* to the temperature difference, i.e. $\frac{d}{dt} \left(T(t)-T_{cool}(t) \right) = -k \cdot \left(T(t) - T_{cool}(t) \right)$ , this gives a different result for (4) in your answer. Is this difference relevant?

Comment: I've never heard or seen that formulation. I believe it to be wrong (and it would give a different result, yes). The modern version of NCL is about the *heat flux* flowing from the hot object to the cold one being *proportional to the temperature difference between the two objects*. The formulation you cite doesn't do that and has to be considered *wrong*. Where did you find it?

Comment: That formulation would be identical to 'mine' if $T_{cool}=\text{Constant}$.

Comment: On page 22 of [A Heat Transfer Textbook](https://ahtt.mit.edu/), which seemed like a reasonably reliable source as it was written by two MIT professors.

Comment: I see, I had assumed they meant that $T_{\infty}$ or $T_{env}$ should have also been included if it depended on time.

Comment: The book (nice book, thank you, useful for heat transfer nutters like me) is correct because $T_{\infty}=\text{Constant}$ Their formula is simply the way they (and I) integrate the DE. No problems at all.

Comment: Gotcha, and my bad for the misinterpretation!